# Why ${(%):-%N} to get expansion of % escapes in zsh?

Tags: zsh

To get the path of a currently running script people suggest to use `${(%):-%N}`. I have looked into this and I cannot wrap my head around why `${(%)%N}` shouldn't work.

From reading the manual (zshexpn) it seems like the above command uses `${name:-value}` which returns the value of `name` if this is set (and non-null), otherwise `value`. In the case above `name` is left blank, in which case `value` is always returned.

The first `(%)` is a parameter expansion flag that (as far as I understand) should make all % escapes (`%N` in this case) expand in the same way as in the prompt.

Shouldn't it be possible to simply use `${(%)%N}` instead? This does not work, but I do not understand why.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Perhaps my understanding of how ${(%):-%N} is parsed is not correct?

Comment: BTW,  you may have better luck using `$ZSH_ARGZERO` for the script name. The `funcstack` and `functrace` arrays from the `zsh/parameter` module are also very useful (see the `zshmodules` man page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `${...}` is for a parameter expansion, and in this case `%N` is not a parameter - it's a string literal. The `:-` syntax is a way to turn a string literal into a parameter.

Some examples that may help explain this:

```bash
> parm='%N'
> print ${parm}
%N
> print -- ${(%)parm}
-zsh
> print X${notaparameter}X
XX
> print X${%N}X
XX
> print X${:-%N}X
X%NX
> print X${(%):-%N}X
X-zshX
```

Comment: Aha, now I see. Using the `(%)` will expand percentage escapes of the result of `${%N}` (which returns nothing). So, using the `:-` will be equivalent to the following: first evaluate `${:-%N}`, and since the left hand side is none, this will return the string literal `%N`. Now, use prompt expansion on this.